# ethersjs Non deterministic uncompressed key recovery from digest and signature

Tags: ethers.js, public-key, recover

I'm trying to take the [signed coinbase data](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getcoinbasepriceoracle) produce a deterministic output for the same uncompressed key (starting with 04).

I'm using the following example data from the api:

```
{
    "messages": [
      "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062f9360400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a720ef700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006707269636573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034254430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062f9360400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007332e3f80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006707269636573000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034554480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    ],
    "signatures": [
      "0xaf834758a351608e8ba3acb4ec835d9e9bb92a4e5d3586a5ad8eee7282da458941272b9ab0ae97d6a0bbec7db4e6af345b46d45d9d608dbf26d0b3929d63eab8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c",
      "0xcdf9d063ba9c6cde75c905f53aac95edb35ee1ed07a14b573f27027618aee5e13b48d083baf8cec14bdfe9fbc4a6da6bdec349af756b3d108faaa0e91e652ed7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c",
    ]
}
```

And using etherjs to try and produce the uncompressed public key output, but getting different uncompressed keys:

```
for(const i in inputJson.signatures) {
    // cleaing tailing 0's
    const cleaned = inputJson.signatures[i].substring(2).substring(0,128) + inputJson.signatures[i].substring(inputJson.signatures[i].length-2);
    const r = cleaned.substring(0,64);
    const s = cleaned.substring(64,128);
    const v = cleaned.substring(128);
    trx.r = `0x${r}`;
    trx.s = `0x${s}`;
    trx.v = `0x${v}`;
    console.log('i',i,'\n','r',trx.r,'\n', 's',trx.s,'\n', 'v',trx.v,'\n');
    let v_val = trx.v == '0x1c' ? 28 : 27;
    let signature = ethers.utils.concat([ trx.r, trx.s, [ v_val ] ]);
    console.log(
        'uncompressed key: ',
        ethers.utils.recoverPublicKey(
            ethers.utils.arrayify(
                ethers.utils.keccak256(inputJson.messages[i])
            ),
            signature
        ),'\n'
    );
}

r 0xaf834758a351608e8ba3acb4ec835d9e9bb92a4e5d3586a5ad8eee7282da4589 
s 0x41272b9ab0ae97d6a0bbec7db4e6af345b46d45d9d608dbf26d0b3929d63eab8 
v 0x1c 

uncompressed key:  0x04d64caf252cf3631b780cfaeabd4c21a1f4b39a7703102ed7e9d99b634434456591a8f43456173c7b4f6a1b4eaaf2143d6d34acbe688e266968acbd0ba2c8cf19 

r 0xcdf9d063ba9c6cde75c905f53aac95edb35ee1ed07a14b573f27027618aee5e1 
s 0x3b48d083baf8cec14bdfe9fbc4a6da6bdec349af756b3d108faaa0e91e652ed7 
v 0x1c 

uncompressed key:  0x048bb556974e2f0973da6c6484be7194d6884b7a1e24749562ee87ac9c6f6672f1ad6abeb4ab17ad82af1b0304c207d0ded440cdc6455cf15eced9b1cec77e7509
```

I'm able to recover with web3js for the simplified public key no problem, just cannot for the uncompressed key.

```
record = Object.values(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['string', 'uint', 'string', 'uint'], messages[i])).slice(0, -1);

adr = web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.utils.keccak256(messages[i]), signatures[i], false); 

console.log(record, adr === '0xfCEAdAFab14d46e20144F48824d0C09B1a03F2BC' ? 'signature OK' : 'BAD signature!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I was not performing the create signature hash verification.

The following is an example of how you would get an uncompressed key from signature recovery.

https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eosio-coinbase-price-feed/blob/main/api/recover.js#L524

The following article also goes into details on the signature scheme as well as notes the uncompressed key. https://medium.com/@NatPDeveloper/eosio-coinbase-price-feed-contract-34e35e6c765b